# UserControl in same project

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a simple WPF Control project with 1 window and 1 custom user control.  I built the project and the control showed up on the toolbox - great.  I dragged a couple instances of the control onto the window and it worked as expected - great again.  It added an xmlns for 'my' that referenced it's own base namespace and put in the proper references for the controls - perfect.

Then I tried to build it, not so perfect.  It appears that it is looking for it's own build dll so when it starts to build the project and deletes the dll then suddenly it can't find the namespace reference so the build fails.  Then the dll is missing so the designer gives the error.  I can delete the reference to this namespace which fixes the error and I can rebuild successfully, which returns the dll which means I can paste the reference back in with no errors... until I try to build again...

Is there any way to do this without making every control it's own dll?

Comment: Ok, well I got it working although I'm a little confused on how.  I first tried to break it into another project so it would compile to another .dll, but it was doing the same thing.  I tried to create a new project with a super simple control (1 button) and a blank form and it worked...

Continued below...

Comment: I recreated the simple control in my project, and that worked too...  I added in the XAML (litterally copy/paste) from the other control in parts to see what was breaking it, but it still worked...

The only dif. I can see is that this time it used the fully qualified namespace to declare the xmlns and the .cs file; last time it used just the closest common namespace.  Not sure why that changed it but it seems to have...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a rebuild on release?

Designer errors don't stop my compiles. But the designer error doesn't go away until release is built.

Check your build settings.